# Error while creating qmake for a Qt static build

Tags: qt, qmake, static-linking

I got stuck trying to build Qt libraries statically with this command:

```
/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0 $ ./configure -static -prefix /strg/Qt
```

and getting this response:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ /strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/configure -top-level -static -prefix /strg/Qt
./configure: 49: exec: /strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/configure: not found
```

I attempted to resolve this using vim command `set userformat=unix` on the file `qtbase/configure`.

After running the same line `/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0 $ ./configure -static -prefix /strg/Qt` things are no better:

```
Creating qmake...
’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
.
```

I am following the instructions on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html and I guess, I could make a mistake during the previous steps. Could you help me?

Comment: What is your `/path/to/Qt` ?

Comment: Here it is `/strg/Qt/`. Sources are stored inside `/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/`

Comment: then whats `/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0`

Comment: Source files are stored there

Comment: Following link you shared,  your `-prefix`  should be `/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0`

Comment: Then you get the linked libraries under `/strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your sources are in /strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0. I prefer having separate build and install dirs:

Create build dir, e.g. /strg/Qt/build and create install dir, e.g. /strg/Qt/install

Go to build dir:

```
cd /strg/Qt/build
```

Run configure from your build dir and give install dir using -prefix:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure -static -prefix /strg/Qt/install
```

Other useful configure parameters you might use (don't skip qtwebengine if you need it, if you don't need it you save lots of time by skipping it)

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure -opensource -confirm-license -static -release -prefix /strg/Qt/install -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine
```

Comment: `bash ../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure -static -prefix /strg/Qt/Install + cd qtbase + /strg/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/configure -top-level -static -prefix /strg/Qt/Install`  `Preparing build tree...`
`Creating qmake...` 
`make: *** [main.o] Error 1`
This is what I get after running `configure` from `/strg/Build`

Comment: Did you get your sources messed up? What if you extract clean sources and try again? Remember to empty your build dir before trying again. What is your Linux and what is your gcc version?

Comment: The same error, actually. I think, the problem can be in the files format. I'll try to download a different archive from the qt archives https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.0/.

Comment: On Linux you should take https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.0/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0.tar.xz

Comment: Mint 18.3 sylvia and gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0

Comment: Ok, this is the first time I meet this incompatibility problem :D I will try .tar.xz as soon as possible.

Comment: Always use source tarball on Linux, and zip on Windows only.